# Priority-Web-SDK: Postman error "screen not prepared" error

Tags: javascript, postman, erp

I am working on an application that connects with a [Priority server](https://prioritysoftware.github.io/) via API (and/or SDK)

Suddenly my connections were failing.

While testing using [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/), sending just the serviceRoot returns the expected list of forms.  Adding "/PORDERS" returns the error:

```
מסך =filter אינו מוכן.
```

formatted exactly like that.  I get the same response regardless of whether the form is flagged as Available for API or not.

If I run a simple filter/select `serviceRoot/PART?$filter=TYPE eq 'R'&$select=PARTNAME,TYPE`

I get the response: (including formatting)

```
מסך filter=TYPE = R אינו מוכן.
```

All of the Forms are fully prepared and work without problem within Priority, and all of these error responses come with a [`403 Forbidden`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403) status.

Is this a server error?  A Priority permissions error?  Or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems that the answer here has to do with multiple Priority installations on a single server.  When an installation is updated or a new one is installed, this can lead to errors including the above mentioned one.

Priority, as it seems, does not support multiple installations.  It is not clear to me at this point if this is a general Priority issue, or something specific to the API module.

Re-installation of priority seems to alleviate the problem.

[Note: if this answer does not feel 100% complete, that is because I am not a systems person, and am trying to understand what was explained to me.]

**UPDATE:**  It appears that IIS does not always update with Priority.  Sometimes a simple IIS `restart` does the job.